# multiplying two metrics

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ and $(X,d^\prime)$ are metric spaces ,is $d×d^\prime$ metric on $X$ ?I try to prove triangle inequality , I write two triangle inequalities for $d $ and $ d^\prime$ but it not true.

Comment: There are metrics $d$ and $d'$ such that $dd'$ is a metric. But it is not always a metric. So to solve the problem, you should come up with metrics $d$ and $d'$ such that $dd'$ is not a metric. Hint: You can use a familiar space, and $d=d'$.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand what you mean with $d \times d'$. Recall that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space then $d:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function which assigns to a pair $(x,y) \in X\times X$, $d(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$ so I find the use of $\times$ certainly ambiguous

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado : That's ambiguous, but I would guess that's $(x, y)\mapsto d(x, y)d'(x, y)$.

Answer (score 1):

I find an example so the the product is not a metric. Consider $d(x,y)=|x-y|=d^\prime(x,y)$, then $d×d^\prime=(x-y)^2$ is not a metric.